# Prevent text wrapping to next line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am newbie in Twitter Bootstrap. It is a very simple question.

Here is the image:

[image: Paragraph]

And here is my **Code**:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-6 col-sm-6  placeholders">
  <p id="people-things" class="text-center"><a href="#">PEOPLE-THINGS RECOMENDATION</a></p>
</div>
```

**Problem**: I want to put the `Recomendation` text in one line other then going in next line.

**Infos**: I had tried every grid in but still couldn't sort it out.

Comment: If you can create the demo using code, that will be good.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to make smaller `font-size` on `.people-things` or add this CSS:

```
.people-things { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Which is making `.people-things` to show on one line.

Comment: Thanks man You saved my day. ! and could you tell me please where you learned the bootstrap other then its official documentation?

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` is just a simple CSS, not something from bootstrap.  Very good series for learning CSS are "30 Days to Learn HTML & CSS" - http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/30-days-to-learn-html-css Also if my post has helped you please approve it.

Comment: Thank you @Viktor if you think my post would gonna help someone out their, please vote it :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution above works but bootstrap grid classes should be ideally used by itself and you should not need any custom styles on top of it.
Try rearranging your grid structure such that apply `<col-sm-6>` before `<col-xs-6>`. That will allow more space in the grid cell to fit the text. Also you might not need three levels of grid nesting. You could use: `<col-md-8><col-sm-8>` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks but using col-sm-6 before col-xs-6 whats the difference? xs is evaluated first ever irrespective of the position.